# OpenLayers : Wrong coordinates on moving window

Tags: dictionary, window, openlayers

I am using the OpenLayers library for rendering a map in my web-page.
The map is displayed in a pop-up window.

I am querying the latitude and longitude using getLonLatFromPixel.

But, whenever I move the map window, it shows wrong coordinates.

Eg, If I move the map window to the right, it adds some value in the correct coordinates.